# How to burn a program in flash in IAR Workbench?

Tags: iar

I am using IAR Embedded Workbench IDE to develop an embedded solution for the Renesas RL78/G13.  I am able to compile and run the project in debug mode.  Now I would like to burn the program to flash in release mode.  Can someone tell me how to do this?

Comment: I found a solution that works for me.  Go to project>options>linker>output.  Then, under file name, click "override default" to change the file name to "myproject.hex". Under format, click "Other" and select Intel hex format and click OK.  Recompile the project.  Then use the Renesas Flash Programmer (available for free from renesas.com) to program the flash memory.  If someone else can tell me how to program the flash through IAR instead of using the Renesas Flash Programmer, that would be appreciated.

Comment: no go for me - options have significantly changed

Answer (score 2):

Maybe the answer is a little bit late, but another option straight from IAR is to go to Make [F7 key] the project and the go to Menu Project -> Download -> Download active application.

Be carefull that the Reset line of the microncontroller is free so nothing sets it to OV, which will stop the microcontroller from running

IAR version for RL78 1.40.1

Answer (score 0):

Certainly, you can use the Renesas Flash Programmer for downloading the hex file into the microcontroller. The Renesas flash Programmer install package, you can get from the website from supplier.